# Inner-most disk arguments

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two smoothly embedded disks in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\partial D_1 = \partial D_2$ and both disks intersect transversely on their interiors. Then there exists a $C\subset D_1\cap D_2$ such that $C$ bounds an inner most disk in both $D_1$ and $D_2$.

I believe this is true but I cant figure out a way to prove it for any pair of disks. Most papers which use "a standard inner most disk argument" dont provide any insight into why this should be true. A reference or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: By transversality $D_1 \cap D_2$ is a 1-dimensional submanifold with boundary. Maybe by using $\partial D_1 = \partial D_2$ this submanifold has to be closed. Then it is a union of circles, bounding disks in $D_1,D_2$ respectively.

Comment: @Jonas well it turns out the statement is false. I was given a counterexample which I'll provide below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D_b$ and $D_r$ (for black and red disks) be the two disks obtained by rotating the picture below about the y-axis. As you spin the figure about the y-axis, the inner most circle in $D_b$ is the boundary for an annulus in $D_r$ and similarly for the inner most circle for $D_r$.

[image: Disks]

Comment: Ah I didn't read your question carefully. Is there a definition for "the innermost disk" in $D_b$ ?

Comment: Not really for "the" innermost disk. The example however has a single innermost disk for each disk.

Comment: I'd tried coming up with a rotationally symmetric counterexample last night -- nice to see there actually was one!